# Can I run all tests extending specific superclass from gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a relatively large code-base at hand. It consists of loads of integration tests with a handful or two of abstract test base classes. As I am currently working on running all these tests with in-memory h2 rather than Oracle, it would be useful to be able to run tests of a given class hierarchy so I can fix one hierarchy at a time.

Ideally, something similar to:

```
$ gradlew test -DtestHierarchy=AbstractTestSuperClass
```

would run all tests extending from `AbstractTestSuperClass`

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: package them together and execute all tests from that package.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did think of that and gave it a shot before asking. The problem is the size of the code base and that the concrete test classes are spread on multiple modules with quite different dependencies. Grouping these together as suggested would be a very tedious job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the feature you're looking for is already a feature requested and inlined in Gradle's list.

Gradle's documentation over [Test Filtering](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#test_filtering) states that some of the test-filtering scenarios Gradle handles now and some will be satisfied in future releases:

> - Filtering at the level of specific test methods; executing a single test method
> - Filtering based on custom annotations (future)
> - **Filtering based on test hierarchy; executing all tests that extend a certain base class (future)**
> - Filtering based on some custom runtime rule, e.g. particular value of a system property or some static state (future)

OR for now, you can name your test classes your their grouping to match any of the [`TestFilters.`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestFilter.html)

---

Also, on a side note as mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539541/can-i-run-all-tests-extending-specific-superclass-from-gradle/46539855#comment80033296_46539541), you should consider refactoring your code to place such classes into one `package`. IMO, having large code-base shouldn't be a problem, but having it unaligned would always be.